# Segmentation fault when reading data from file and printing it

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, codeblocks

I am trying to use results from a different code into a new one. I am required to read a numerical-type formatted data. I am a novice at coding in Fortran. The output suggests "segmentation fault". I am not sure, how my code needs to be modified or do I need to change some settings in the compiler.

```
  program main
  implicit none
  double precision,dimension(101):: p,q
  integer:: i,j
  write(*,*) "Hello World!"
  open(10,file='C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\test\results_analytical.dat',status='old',action='read')
  do i=1,101
    write(10,1) p(i),q(i)
  end do
  1 format(1f14.10,1f14.10,1f14.10)
  close(10)
  do j=1,10
    write(*,*) p(j),q(j)
  end do
end program main
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. When asking, make sure your post is properly formatted. Use the `\`\`\`` marks and not the asterisks, those make the ordinary text bold. Or use the buttons provided in the edit window. Note that the language has been called Fortran, not FORTRAN, for three decades.

Comment: To better diagnose the problem you should also give us the compiler command you use and the content of your data file.

Answer (score -1):

Your file is opened for reading, but you use the `write` statement, not the `read` statement to read the data. I am not sure why it does not give you a better error message.

I suggest enabling all the debugging options for your compiler. I am not sure how it is done in Code::Blocks.

Comment: Maybe the question should be closed as a typo instead of answering? I posted this as a community wiki because it is trivial.